# Telerik Radscheduler for Winform multiple appointments within one slot

Tags: winforms, telerik, radscheduler

I am using Telerik Radscheduler for **Winform**, every time a new appointment is added, the whole slot is taken by default, I cannot add another appointment in the same slot.

I read their [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/scheduler/appointments-and-dialogs/working-with-appointments) for Winform but there is no instruction on how to enable it.

However in their [DEMO](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) of Telerik RadScheduler for **ASP.NET** Scheduler apparently you can add multiple appointments within one slot.

I am wondering if it is something that only available in Telerik RadScheduler for **ASP.NET**, anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the provided information, it is not very clear which scheduler's view type you are using. However, I suppose that it is the default one which is DayView: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/scheduler/views/day-view

When you add an appointment to RadScheduler, it occupies the associated time slot according to the ruler's hours on the left and date column above:

[image]

You are allowed to add other appointments for the same time slot either via the context menu or by double-clicking an empty cell:

[image]

This will invoke the edit dialog which allows you to edit the appointment's information together with the time slot it occupies.

However, if you are still experiencing any further difficulties, feel free to submit a support ticket from your Telerik account providing details about the precise case and the undesired behavior that you are facing. Thus, the Telerik support engineers will gladly assist you: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-submit-a-support-ticket

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am using default day view. I have a custom context menu which have different items. I will try the default context menu and see what I can get from there.